# How set the Url of the created game in Telegram BotFather?

Tags: botframework, webhooks, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have created a new game in BotFather Telegram. But there was not any question about game link. Also, there is not any parameter to set game url in "sendGame" function. How can I set my gameUrl behind the created game in BotFather?

I should say, I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework to develope my bot.

Comment: you managed to solve?

Answer (score 0):

They say you have to use the answerCallbackQuery method

> "URL that will be opened by the user's client. If you have created a
>   Game and accepted the conditions via @Botfather, specify the URL that
>   opens your game – note that this will only work if the query comes
>   from a callback_game button.
>
> Otherwise, you may use links like telegram.me/your_bot?start=XXXX that
>   open your bot with a parameter."

Comment: "?start=xxxx" is not related to my question. Anyhow, as I found from your solution, you said that I should respond to a wanted game via an inline bot? Is it true? Could you write a sample code to clarify your solution?

Answer (score 0):

i solve in this way:

```
if(isset($update["callback_query"])) {
  $parameters["method"] = "answerCallbackQuery";
  $parameters["callback_query_id"] = $update["callback_query"]["id"];
  $parameters["url"] = "<url_game>";
  echo json_encode($parameters);
}

$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId);
// method è il metodo per l'invio di un messaggio (cfr. API di Telegram)
$parameters["method"] = "sendGame";
$parameters["game_short_name"] = "prova";
```

Explanation:
In the first part is sent to the photo set from botfather. When you decide to play a callback_query you are created. We must send then the url of our html5 code

Comment: Do you mean we should send two methods to do this? If I want send a game directly to a user, I will not have any callback_query id.

Comment: Yes, We, too, are comparing them with the assistance we found soloist That way